# Mordenkainen 's disjunction and Mage's disjunction how to protect yourself?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

On arriving at level 18 , you can find NPCs with Mordenkainen 's disjunction , how to protect beyond the chance of antimagic field ?

Losing the properties of magic items is not good for a group.

What class or magic should use to protect yourself ?

Answer (score 5):

There are all sorts of ways, depending on the resources available to the near-epic level party. What follows is a short list of normal precautions which should be taken against *all* of the save-or-lose spells of that level.

- Every party member who doesn't have more critical rings to wear should wear Greater Rings of Counterspells situated against the most annoying save-or-lose spells currently in play. DMG2, at 16,000 gp per pop, it's absolutely worth enchanting this into custom slotless magical items if you can.
- Agree to the truce of "no first use," as the party's use of disjunction (or other insta-suck spells) can be just as not-fun to the DM as the DM's is to the party.
- Craft contingent spell (CArc), Greater Dispel Magic
- Enchant duelward (CArc) into a custom magical item (or otherwise persist it as part of your suite of normally-applied spells) Also enchant battlemagic perception (Heroes of Battle) into that suite.
- Prepare any number of high-level swift action counterspelling spells.
- Have casters wear on their other ring slot "Rings of Spellbattle" (complete mage)
- Have opposing casters decide their [differences over a cup of tea](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-201003.html).

Characters who *need* to play at this level of competence, however, will quickly eclipse most of the game in the logistics, preparation, and execution of this deadly "wizard tag".

Answer (score 2):

Most people I know avoid using *mage's disjunction* on the PCs, with the precise intent of not having them need to re-equip from scratch.

Some DMs, including some people on this site, just avoid using the spell in their campaigns altogheter, reasoning that high level spells were never playtested and some were really bad ideas to begin with, because of how unfun they are.

A way one could stop a disjunction from happening could be readying a counterspell (please note how counterspells are a pretty ineffective tactic), or people could have a contingent *teleport* (either with *contingence* or Craft Contingent Spells) to exit the area of the disjunction on the moment it's cast (the BBEG of my last D&D3.5 campaign did that). Of course, this is a contingence you're not using to defend from something else, and possibly a waste of resources.