# Which Epic Spells don't follow the Epic Spell rules?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, epic-tier

As has [recently been pointed out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/197734/53359), the pre-statted Epic Spell [Superb Dispelling](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/spells/superbDispelling.htm) has a limitation that the [Dispel Seed](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/seeds/dispel.htm) ought not to grant. Ignoring the DM's ability to approve anything, what other [pre-statted Epic spells](https://www.d20srd.org/indexes/epicSpells.htm) do not follow the rules of their corresponding seeds?

Answer (score 5):

### None of them.

The epic spell rules are, in summary, "make some stuff up".

The spell seeds are interesting, but do not have a strict mechanical effect. They are suggested parts of a spell that you make up in cooperation with your DM.

So, given that, literally nothing falls outside the rules of "make some stuff up".

Comment: This is quite plausible. For example, the [Time Duplicate Epic Spell](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/spells/timeDuplicate.htm) plainly says that its DC has an ad hoc component. However, I'd be surprised if none of them just use the seeds exactly as intended.

Comment: @J.Mini there’s a negative in the question. All epic spells conform to the rules (because the rules have no real constraints). None of them “don’t follow” the rules. I have the same intuition as you that some examples probably follow a reasonably consistent approach to using the seeds, but I would also be very surprised if anyone came up with a rigorous, rules-based explanation for which seeds are even applicable.